# How to show real analyticity without extending to complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity

Suppose we have some $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}).$  For example, $$f(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}.$$  Using complex analysis, we can easily show $f$ is real analytic.  Is there an easy, general method to show this which doesn't use complex analysis?

Comment: How about $f(x)=\sum\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$?

Comment: Not really easy, but there are growth conditions for the derivatives that ensure that the remainder term in the Taylor approximation tends to $0$ uniformly in a neighbourhood of the centre of the expansion. Seeing that it's the restriction of a holomorphic function is usually much easier.

Comment: Not general, but the function $f(x) = (1 + x^{2})^{-1}$ is "obviously" analytic: $g(x) = (1 + x)^{-1} = \bigl[(1 + a) + (x - a)\bigr]^{-1}$ has a geometric series expansion about an arbitrary real number $a$, $h(x) = x^{2}$ is polynomial, and $f = g \circ h$.

Comment: [General, yes; easy, not necessarily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Alternative_characterizations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sums, products, quotients, and compositions of real analytic functions are real analytic. So in your example, $1+x^2$ is real-analytic, and so is $1/x,$ hence so is $1/(1+x^2).$

Answer (score 1):

The most popular *general method* is to calculate the general term $f^{(n)}(a)$, and if that's possible, and for every $a$, find an interval $[a-h,a+h]$, such that
if 
$$
M_n=\max_{x\in[a-h,a+h]}\lvert \,f^{(n)}(x)\rvert,
$$
then
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{k_n}{n!}\right)^{\!1/n}=L<\infty.
$$
The $M_n$ can be approximated using Taylor expansion remainder.